# How do you turn off XML code completion in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-completion

In IntelliJ IDEA if you open an XML document and start entering XML

<body name=

Then the software immediately and undesirably adds untyped quote characters

<body name=""

Without realizing there is extra input I continue to type a quote character followed by the value of the property followed by another quote character

<body name=""value""

and that's a syntax error.

The preferences has a whole section for Auto Completion and I unchecked every box. That didn't change anything, the XML editor still does it. How is this feature controlled?

Answer (score 2):

Disable `Add quote for attribute...` under **Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys | HTML/CSS**
[image]